# ECSSlidingViewController, how to move to a specific view programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using an ECSSlidingViewController (on iPhone) it works perfectly but I would like to do something special.

In my App I have an ECSSlidingViewController, a Menu (UITableViewController) for the underLeftViewControllerStoryboardId and several others UINavigationViewController when a menu entry is selected.

A user can navigate from the Mail App to my App using an attachment in the mail. When this navigation happens (and the App was already started) I need to display one of the UINavigationViewController from my Menu.

I'm able to display the Menu anywhere the user is in the App hierarchy with the following code

```
    ECSlidingViewController* viewController = [DataCenter sharedInstance].slidingViewController;

[viewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:FALSE];
```

Next, I'm not able to display on the full screen the UINavigationViewController I would like to show.

Any idea how to do that?
Thanks for your help

Sébastien.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using storyboards:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardIdOfNavigationController"];
[self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: That's correct I'm using storyboard. My UINavigationViewController already exists and I have a reference on it. I just need to understand how to slide it.

Comment: Updated my answer to reset the top view.